# Run time error in C

Tags: c, runtime-error, file-handling, c-strings

My code gives a run time error when I reach the middle of the file.
If I change the values of temp2 or temp1 then it crashes at the start of the file.
I can't understand the error I am making in this file.

It runs smoothly on a small file which has 100 lines.

I am making a file searching project so I need to store big files which have directories of entire drives.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
char file[99999];
void brek(char *p, char *q);
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    int g = 0;
    char temp1[10000];          // temp1 is simply for jumping to the date against the given directory or file
        // the main array storing the lines is temp2.
     char temp2[1000][1000];

    system("chdir C:\\Users\\Faraz\\Documents && dir /s > dir.txt");
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Faraz\\Documents\\dir.txt", "r");

    while ((y = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        file[x] = y;
        x++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    file[x] = '\0';
    puts(&file[0]);

    // <----the copying of the file to the string "file (globally declared)"is
    // done---->//

    getche();
    system("cls");

    // <-------------------start loop-------------------->//

    a = 0;
    while (file[a] != '\0')     // <-------starting of the loop
    {

        while (file[a] != '/')
        {
            temp1[a] = file[a];
            a++;
        }
        temp1[a] = '\0';

        a = a - 2;
        b = 0;
        while (file[a] != '\n')
        {
            temp2[g][b] = file[a];
            b++;
            a++;
        }
        temp2[g][b] = '\0';
        puts(&temp2[g][0]);

        g++;

    }
    // <-----------------end loop---------------------->//

}
```

Comment: Why are you using system when system calls would be better?

Comment: You need dynamic memory allocation

Comment: Yes, above comments apply, but your major issue is that you're using the variable `a` for different things in the main loop: it's indexing both `file` and `temp1`.

Comment: @iharob i am a newbie how will dynamic memory allocation help me?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker it helps to discard the additional information in the directory listing and jumps to the part where i can work on the  name of the file or the directory

Comment: But if you're using a single index into arrays of different sizes, at some point you're asking for trouble. And frankly, I'm with Ed: this whole design is hideous, escaping to the shell and parsing a text listing meant for humans. Learn to use `dirent` (or whatever the Windows equivalent of that is).

Comment: @Zimad: dynamic memory allocation will allow you to avoid allocating a megabyte of data on the stack (which may only have 8 MiB available for use, possibly less if you're on Windows), and on small files may use much less memory and on enormous (multi-gigabyte) files won't crash.  If you're wanting to deal with large files, you will need dynamic memory allocation to avoid trouble.

Comment: Here might be a good starting point http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: If the value of `x` after reading the file is 99999 or more, then `file[]` is too small.  Needs to be larger or use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @Zimad you only want the names of the files?

Comment: @iharob yes i will use them for file searching

Comment: regarding this line: 'void main()' that is not a valid main function, rather use either 'int main()' or 'int main( int argc, char * argv[] )'  Of course, for either proper main function there should always be some returned value, usually 0, at the end of the function.

Comment: the conio.h file is for the DOS int 24 functions.  Not really what you want for a windows program.

Comment: @user3629249 then how do i use getche() ?

Comment: Minus one for the single-letter var names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
int 
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA fdFile;
    HANDLE hFind = NULL;
    const char *sPath = "C:\\Users\\Faraz\\Documents\\*.*";

    if((hFind = FindFirstFile(sPath, &fdFile)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("no such directory %s\n", sPath);
        return -1;
    }

    do
    {
        printf("Directory: %s\n", fdFile->cFileName);
    }
    while(FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile)); //Find the next file.

    FindClose(hFind); //Always, Always, clean things up!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a windows machine so couldn't test the code, show me the errors and I'll try to help you.

Comment: @Zimad try it now, and then delete the errors comments.

Comment: it gives output no directory exist

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? and is it `no directory exists` or `no such directory`?

Comment: sorry my bad it was no such directory and yes the path was correct

Comment: stackoverflow is giving a notification that we should move it to chat. is it safe to do a conversation on comments?

Comment: You don't have enough reputation, so we can't move to a chat, and check if the path is really ok.

Comment: yes path is correct.....it gives an error on this line     printf("Directory: %s\n", fdFile.cFileName);.....it gives an output when i change it to fdFile->cFileName as it is a pointer

Comment: no the output is no such directory......i changed the directory to c but still output is consistent

Answer (score 0):

THe answer i found out is that you simply cant load a 1gb file in a 512 mb memory.
So we define buffer size at the top of the string using

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 512
```

and using fgets we read the file line - by - line hence not overloading our memory space allocated by OS.

Dynamic Memory Allocation is not the solution to our problem as we start using heap space.